# SignalR Is it safe to send sensitive data to the host via Connection Header?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr.client

I want to use SingalR in C# and .Net-Framework with Authorization and send sensitive data like username and password to the Host with the Connection Header to initiate the correct specific Role for the user.

Now my Question is, how safe is the Connection Header?

 Are the Objects which are send to the Host encrypted like in SSH or can anyone read the sended headers like a string?

Comment: Authorization generally assumes that you have some form of authentication, so you must pass the user's credentials through the authentication header. For example, username and password are the authentication type Basic.